# Url Storage Laravel cannot display image

Tags: laravel-5

I have this url codes to call my image in laravel storage

```
<img src="{{url('/storage/logo/') }}/{{ $logo }}" alt="abcd" width="50px" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
```

but it didn't show up.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First issue you have you are passing two `/`'s in your image code (one after logo and out outside of the blade syntax).

More importantly, storage assets can't be shown on the front end by default

Firstly, you will need to run the `php artisan storage:link` artisan command to have the storage folder accessible. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk) for more info.

Lastly, you can use the `asset()` helper to show files within the new symbolic folder. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset) for more info

Then you should be able to do the following:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/logo/ . $logo }}" alt="abcd" width="50px" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
```